# count valued of checkboxes

Tags: php, arrays, sum

I'm trying to total the valued of selected checkboxes. I receive individual values, but can't figure out how to total them.

```
<?php 
$q1= isset($_POST["question1"])
? implode(',', $_POST["question1"])
: 'no selection made';
?>
```

Here's my check boxes:

```
 <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="question1[]" value="0" id="question1_0" />
          Not Applicable</label>
        <br />
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="question1[]" value="7.69" id="question1_1" />
          Tells the truth.</label>
        <br />
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="question1[]" value="7.69" id="question1_2" />
          Shows respect for others.</label>
        <br />
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="question1[]" value="7.69" id="question1_3" />
          Is straight forward- does not have a "hidden agenda."</label>
        <br />
        <label>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy, just use [`array_sum`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php):

```
$q = empty($_POST["question1"]) ? 0 : array_sum($_POST["question1"]);
```

Comment: Next question, how can I set this up so that it will work with more than one question?

Comment: @kamalo: Name your fields `question[0][]`, `question[0][]`, ..., `question[N][]`, `question[N][]` so that `$_POST['question']` is an array of arrays. Loop over it and run `array_sum` on each sub-array.